# Nunit ignoring command line parameter for configuration

Tags: command-line, nunit, jenkins

I have some problems trying to use nunit within a jenkins job. Even though the documentation for nunit-2.6 [1] states, that you can specify the build configuration to be used for the tests, this doesn't seem to work. I try to run the tests with the "Release" configuration, but nunit tries to load the Debug assembly and fails :( I start nunit with the following call:

```
nunit-console-x86.exe ambiHomeWPFTest\Tests\Tests.csproj /config:Release
```

Anyone has an idea, what is going on there? I'm quite new to .NET coming from a java background so maybe I miss something simple.

[1] http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6

```
[test_ambiHomeWPFTest_master] $ cmd /c call     C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson8704126216198591607.bat

c:\jenkins\workspace\test_ambiHomeWPFTest_master>nunit-console-x86.exe ambiHomeWPFTest\Tests\Tests.csproj /config:Release 
NUnit-Console version 2.6.0.12051
Copyright (C) 2002-20011 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5456 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Default
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Ein Teil des Pfades     "c:\jenkins\workspace\test_ambiHomeWPFTest_master\ambiHomeWPFTest\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.dll    " konnte nicht gefunden werden.
   bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   bei System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32     rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options,     SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   bei System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   bei NUnit.Core.AssemblyReader.CalcHeaderOffsets()
   bei NUnit.Core.AssemblyReader..ctor(String assemblyPath)
   bei NUnit.Util.RuntimeFrameworkSelector.SelectRuntimeFramework(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.DefaultTestRunnerFactory.GetTargetProcessModel(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.Util.DefaultTestRunnerFactory.MakeTestRunner(TestPackage package)
   bei NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   bei NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)

c:\jenkins\workspace\test_ambiHomeWPFTest_master>exit -100 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Strange? I just checked, and I have no problems using the `/config:Release` switch with NUnit 2.6. You do for certain have a Release version of the DLL at the corresponding Release path with that name?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. 
This is the solution, which contains the Tests project.
http://pastebin.com/jeMBXSbq
The  compilation upfront works http://pastebin.com/UZfb1wLa
and the Tests.dll is inside Tests/bin/Release

Comment: What happens if you make a Debug build of the test assembly?

Comment: It works because nunit uses the Debug configuration instead of Release :(
http://pastebin.com/Bp3xhq4w

Comment: I notice that the system messages are in German. This is just a guess, but maybe there are problems with localization? What happens if you explicitly reference the Release DLL, i.e. `nunit-console-x86 ambiHomeWPFTest\Tests\bin\Release\Tests.dll`?

Comment: Referencing the Release Tests.dll explicitly works also. It's not a real solution, more a work around, but I think I don't have any other choice. Thanks for your help. I guess we will never know, why this parameter won't work here :(

Comment: For consistency, I added this solution as the answer to the question. I hope you are OK with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter problems with the `/config:` switch when referencing a `.csproj` in for example a `nunit-console-x86` command, my recommendation is that you explicitly reference the  DLL of interest instead.

In the scenario above, the call should thus be:

```
nunit-console-x86 ambiHomeWPFTest\Tests\bin\Release\Tests.dll
```

Comment: Thanks, made it now this way, even though it seems more like a work around.